# import csv data to mysaql database in php and show error

Tags: php, mysql, fgetcsv

I want to import csv data file to masql databse in php.

I want to know which line and column have error on data format

Like row no 24 and column phone no : data is not number .

Please help me plzzzzzzzzz

For example I made this function

```
function phoneValidate($phone)
{
    global $err;
    if(ctype_digit($phone) && strlen((string)$phone) == 10)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        array_push($err , "phone");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I use it in validation

```
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    if(phoneValidate())
```

Comment: What have you tried? Copy it here and describe your CSV and your rules after that

Comment: Let me ask my Crystal ball ...., no seriously, without any code and examples of your csv it's is impossible to help you

Comment: Do you have already created a table which fit the needs of your csv file ?

Comment: which code do you want @empiric

Comment: yaa i have done every thing ..like my data is insrting into database ... i jus want to know how would i know which row have a error SIR @Zeratops

Answer (score 0):

To specify the position of your error you can simplay use counters:

```
$i = 1;
while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){
    for ( $x = 0; $x < count ( $emapData ); $x++ )
    {
         if(!validate($emapData[$x])){ //example, $x would be the column
             echo 'Error in line ' . $i . ' on column ' . $x;
         }
    }
    $i++; //row
}
```

I hope I get it right ...